# Nullify Rich Text Area if there is only whitespaces and line breaks

Tags: regex, salesforce, workflow, richtextbox

Am trying to nullify the rich text area field if it contains only whitespaces and line breaks. I should not nullify even there is a single word in the text area. Because it is taking too much space in the UI if it contains. Note - Even there is single work with multiple trailing and leading whitesapces/line breaks it should display as it is.

I constructed a regex which will match for this scenario but it is not passing in workflow entry criteria.

Regex:

> "^[\s<>br/]+$"

Check this regex checker for details - https://regexr.com/ (put above regex and check)

Any help would be appreciated!.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really need is an equivalent to `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)`

```
function IsNullOrWhiteSpace( value) {    
    if (value== null) return true;    
    return value.replace(/\s/g, '').length == 0;
}
```

```js
    function IsNullOrWhiteSpace( value) {    
        if (value== null) return true;    
        return value.replace(/\s/g, '').length == 0;
    }
    
    console.log(IsNullOrWhiteSpace("\t \n   \t"));
    
    var multilineString = "\
    \
    \
      ";
   console.log(IsNullOrWhiteSpace(multilineString));
   console.log(IsNullOrWhiteSpace(" a"));
```

Your rich text control should allow you to get the text as plain text too. Then things get much easier since the whitespace rules of RTF are a bit weird:

> In RTF, the rules for
>   dealing with whitespace are very different:
>   - A space character is
>   meaningless only if it’s the optional meaningless space at the end of
>   a command. Otherwise, every space character means to insert a space
>   character!
>   - A newline can mark the end of the command; but otherwise,
>   it has no effect or meaning.  [Ref](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/rtf-pocket-guide/9781449302047/ch01.html).

Anyways, your regex should in Javaish-lingo look like this:

```
[\\s<>br/]+$
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Since am not doing this in JS, I just need the correct REGEX to match the rich text area whitespaces and line breaks. Am trying to achieve this in Salesforce workflow rule.

Comment: @mohammedazarudeen good luck. You still might suffer from RTF's weird whitespace rules.